# How to turn on audio in substream profile of Onvif

Tags: rtsp, onvif

I work with onvif protocol and when i get profiles there are both have audio encoder configuration, but only first (main-stream) plays sound, how can I turn on audio on the second(Sub-stream) profile ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the different media profiles you can get from the Media and Media2 Services. Probably the second profile does not have any `AudioEncoderConfiguration` and/or `AudioSourceConfiguration` attached to it.

You can use the functions of the [Media Service](https://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/media/ONVIF-Media-Service-Spec.pdf) (if it is Profile S) or [Media 2 Service](https://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/media/ONVIF-Media2-Service-Spec.pdf) (if it is Profile T) to modify the profiles.

Comment: both profiles are same, and in admin panel(Hikvision) i can turn on sound in any profile. But Can i do it in with onvif ?

Comment: re-read my answer ans check the media services. Those services have the functions that you are looking for.

Comment: Are you sure ? Can you call this method !?